# Relation on set A to the second

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have this set:

```
A = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

R is a relation on A:

```
R = {(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,1)}
```

I have to find R^2. How do I do that?

Comment: Use the definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't really understand it, though. Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

For a (binary) [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) $R$ on $A$, the relation $R^2$ is defined as the [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Operations_on_binary_relations) of $R$ with itself:

> $R^2 = \{ (x,z) \mid \exists y \in A \ (xRy \text{ and } yRz) \ \}$.

Thus, $(1,3) \in R^2$ because $(1,2) \in R$ and $(2,3) \in R$.